# How to e.startDefault when e.preventDefault is set?

Tags: javascript

```
function loaded() {
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
}

loaded();
```

At certain times I want to allow default. How can I do that?

Comment: Basically after I run loaded(), I want to un-run it in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want, something like:

```
function loaded() {
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ 
         if (conditionToPreventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } });
}
```

---

Based on your comment, I think you need removeEventListener - see here for explanation:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: Basically after I run loaded(), I want to un-run it in some way.